# How can you validate/test/verify that your Google Content Experiments configuration/integration/setup is working/correct?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, ab-testing, google-experiments, content-experiments

We are integration Google Content Experiments into a CMS implementation and we have found no way of testing if it works. Whenever we make substantial changes in the integration (e.g using the new Experiments API) it takes hours and hours before test results appears.

Does anyone know how we can more quickly/efficient check if a Google Content Experiments (using the new API in particular) integration is working given the delay in Analytics reports?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Cheers,
Daniel

PS: of course we are getting HTTP 200 back from Google

Comment: LEt us see your sample code

Comment: How long does it take for you to see results? I am not seeing results and I wonder if I need to be more patient or to try something else.